# Different appearance for different GPS pins in CommCare's map reports

Tags: commcare, formatting

I am developing a map report in CommCare's report builder. I would like the different GPS points on the map to have a different appearance depending on a filter. For example, if the client at the GPS point is "customer", the pin at that point would appear in green.  If the client at the GPS point is "not a customer", the pin at that point would appear in red.

Is this, or something similar, possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this does not appear to be possible in with a Map report made via Report Builder. An alternative could be to attach a case property that denotes the client type when the pin has been selected.